# How can I decline a smart-contract-transaction?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is it possible to decline a transaction to a contract in Ethereum (with Solidity) ([written here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10602/can-you-decline-a-transaction)

This is a part of my code:

```
  function accept() public payable {
    if (msg.value == 1e18) { //1e18 wei = 1 ether
      // do smth. special
    } else {
      // do nothing
    }
  }
```

I would like to decline a transaction of less than 1 ether, but I can only filter it that way. So if someone does not read that he must send 1 ether and sends more or less, how can I decline it completly?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `require`:

```
function accept() public payable {
    require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    // do smth. special
}
```

If the condition of the `require` is not met, the transaction is reverted.

Comment: Completely agree. Just to avoid an omission, there are edge cases such as `selfdestruct` than can used to forcefully push ether into a contract that doesn't necessarily want or expect it. It's a possible attack vector if the author thinks this is a fail-safe restriction and there is logic based on that assumption.